# Concept does not resolve ambiguity as expected. What's wrong with the code sample?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++-concepts, c++20

I experiment with c++ concepts. Tried to disambiguate a template 'using' clause by using a concept. Here is a simplified sample:

```
namespace A {

template <typename T>
class Array
{
    public:
        typedef double ElementType;

        Array() {}

        ElementType *data() { return nullptr; }
};

template <typename E>
concept bool Engine =
requires(E e) { {e.data()} -> typename E::ElementType *; };

template <typename E>
requires Engine<E>
class Container
{
    public:
        Container() {};
};

} // namespace A

namespace B {

template <typename T>
using Container = A::Container<A::Array<T>>;

} // namespace B

int main()
{
    using namespace A;
    using namespace B;

    Container<double> d;
    return 0;
}
```

This yields the following error:

```
cio.cc: In function 'int main()':
cio.cc:40:3: error: reference to 'Container' is ambiguous
   Container<double> d;
   ^~~~~~~~~
cio.cc:20:7: note: candidates are: 'template<class E>  requires      Engine<E> class A::Container'
 class Container
   ^~~~~~~~~
cio.cc:31:44: note:                 'template<class T> using Container = A::Container<A::Array<T> >'
 using Container = A::Container<A::Array<T>>;
                                        ^
cio.cc:40:13: error: expected primary-expression before 'double'
   Container<double> d;
```

So why is A::Container considered a candidate for Container? double does not fulfil the concepts. Where am I wrong?

Comment: What is `DenseVector`?

Comment: "*Where am I wrong?*" You gave two things in different namespaces the same name, then imported both names into the same location. Don't do that.

Comment: DenseVector is kind of "typo". Sorry. Fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++20 Concepts just doesn't support that use-case. We have overload resolution for functions, but we don't have overload resolution for types or aliases like this.

`Container<dobule>` has to refer to one thing, but it could be either `A::Container` or `B::Container`... so that's ill-formed. There's no "check if this particular class template satisfies the constraints" step here.

Comment: In my naive understanding of template resolution, I would have thought like this: we have Container<double> in main(). There is a template class Container and a using clause. The template class does not fulfil the constraint, therefor no candidate. Thus the using is left as candidate and chosen. Can you tell me the way it really is selected (I know my interpretation is a strong simplification)

Comment: @AlexanderStippler Like I said, there is no "The template class does not fulfill the constraint, therefor no candidate" step. There is only "There is a template class Container and a using clause" step - therefore ambiguous.

Comment: @AlexanderStippler Name lookup for things like types is actually very simple. You go outwards in scope until you find something. If you found _one_ type/object, then you're done. If you find _two_ or _zero_ types/objects, ill-formed. It's only in the function case that we go wild with argument-dependent lookup and overload resolution.

Comment: ok I got it. But I replay don't like the behavior. Without the using clause A::Container is resulting in "constraints not satisfied" and therefor rejected by the compiler and when adding the using clause it is the reason for ambiguity. This does not really match imho.

Comment: @AlexanderStippler *Only* functions overload in C++, nothing else ever does. This is extremely unlikely to ever change.